# Tar Preserve Folder Modified Date

Tags: linux, sysadmin

I'm creating a tarball in a directory which has multiple sub-directories that I need to archive on a monthly basis. The issue is when I go to extract the files/folders for a particular month the top level sub-folders do not retain the modified date.

I am using the following for the tarball

find -type f -newermt 2021-12-01 ! -newermt 2021-12-31 | xargs tar -cvzf 2021-12.tar.gz

It still shows the time of the extract for each folder which I archived instead of when it was modified. Can someone help me out?

I also tried this as recommended on another user post

find -type f -newermt 2021-12-01 ! -newermt 2021-12-31 | xargs tar --atime-preserve -cvzf 2021-12.tar.gz

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't *archive* the actual folders, only the files within. You can see this for yourself by running `tar -tvvf 2021-12.tar.gz` – it's not that the folder entries are missing their mtimes, it's that there aren't any folder entries at all.

(The folders weren't part of tar's input because `find -type f` specifically excludes them.)

Your output needs to include all parent directory paths, preferably after the corresponding files (although GNU tar has `--delay-directory-restore` to deal with misordered entries). Something like this might work:

```
$ find -name '*.c' |
  perl -ne 'print; print while s!/[^/]+$!\n!g' |
  sort -r |
  uniq |
  xargs -d '\n' tar -cvzf out.tgz --no-recursion
```

My other suggestion is to use Git, Borg, or Restic for incremental archives.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do have the sub folder displaying and it is being created


64115 2021-12-28 18:11 ./345524/commercial_Invoice_20211228181153.pdf

Comment: Is this because I am using find first? I'm just trying to understand where the issue is because I had thought that just calling tar with the commands will get what I want.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I was able to just change the command and it is working as expected
[code_block] find . -newermt 2021-12-01 ! -newermt 2021-12-31 | xargs tar -cvzf 2021-12.tar.gz

Comment: What's in your first comment isn't the subfolder at all, it's a file *inside* the subfolder (and the mtime is the *file's* mtime), but it's not the subfolder itself.